# Is there a way to pass environment variable without declaring into docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose, visual-studio-2022, docker-toolbox

I am using Visual Studio docker tooling and adding a docker-compose project to my solution and I am also using F5 debugging experience.

[image]

I am passing some environment variable within `docker-compose-override` file,

```
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=docker
  - AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=super-secret
```

Problem is this file is part of source code and I don't want to check-in this file with `secret`.

Question is, Is there a way to pass environment variable without declaring into docker-compose file ?

**Note -** I am using visual studio F5 and not running docker-compose command something like `docker compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev up`.